# How can I create a Python function that efficiently iterates through a list of dictionaries and matches each dictionary's values to a given tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a series of 2nd level nested dictionaries each with a column of identifiers (example below).

```
Index   ID

20613   0007650087
20614   00B64L8R37
20615   00B46FK959
20616   00B1KHKN05
20617   0008377250
20618   0001013456
20619   0001012268
20620   00B1KHLW60
20621   0006074909
```

I also have another dictionary containing a list of various combinations of the identifiers with an accompanying name (below).

```
IS Label   Combined IDs

IS_1   --> ['0007650087', '00B64L8R37']
IS_2   --> ['0006074909', '00B1KHKN05']
IS_3   --> ['0006074909', '0001012267']
IS_4   --> ['0006074903', '0006074902', '0006074901']
IS_n....   ['m'...]
```

The idea is to define a function that iterates through the 2nd-level nested dictionary, evaluates the IDs, and assigns the appropriate IS label in the following column (e.g. 20613 & 20614 would be matched to IS_1) and then continues looking for other matches.

I managed to create a function that identifies cases when the dictionary only holds an exact match, but I need to check the whole dictionary as oftentimes they hold multiple 'IS'.

The ideal solution would be a function that matches the IS to the specific rows. So something like the below. At the moment my function would not pick any of these up.

```
Index   ID             IS Label
20613   0007650087     IS_1
20614   00B64L8R37     IS_1
20615   00B46FK959    
20616   00B1KHKN05     IS_2
20617   0008377250
20618   0001013456
20619   0001012268
20620   00B1KHLW60
20621   0006074909     IS_2
```

Comment: please add more context to this question, we need to have concrete examples with a sample from the data (could be artificial) so we can help, also would be nice if added some code to see what you were trying

Comment: I tried adding more information, hope that helps. I don't mind sharing the parts of the code or more specific details, but they are related to finance hence I don't wish for someone without knowledge of this matter to miss the point. I tried to make it more 'general' for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are *ambiguous* but you can still try this :

```
df["IS?"] = df["ID"].map({e: k for (k,lst) in d2.items() for e in lst})
```

Output :

```
print(df)

               ID   IS?
20613  0007650087  IS_1
20614  00B64L8R37  IS_1
20615  00B46FK959   NaN
20616  00B1KHKN05  IS_2
20617  0008377250   NaN
20618  0001013456   NaN
20619  0001012268   NaN
20620  00B1KHLW60   NaN
20621  0006074909  IS_3
```

Used inputs :

```
d1 = {
    20613: '0007650087',
    20614: '00B64L8R37',
    20615: '00B46FK959',
    20616: '00B1KHKN05',
    20617: '0008377250',
    20618: '0001013456',
    20619: '0001012268',
    20620: '00B1KHLW60',
    20621: '0006074909'
}

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": d1})

d2 = {
    'IS_1': ['0007650087', '00B64L8R37'],
    'IS_2': ['0006074909', '00B1KHKN05'],
    'IS_3': ['0006074909', '0001012267']
}
```

Comment: Thank you and apologies if it's not very clear, I'm still struggling to explain it properly with the correct coding terminology! The output of the above wouldn't be correct given `20616` and `20621` should both be matched to `IS_2`. the challenge I'm facing is that many of the identifiers inside the 'identifier_lists' are repeated across various 'IS'. Hence, I only want the function the append the IS label to the rows **if** it can find both identifiers (e.g. finding both `['0007650087', '00B64L8R37']`). Does that explain it better?

Comment: I can see that `0006074909` belongs to both `IS_2` and `IS_3`. How do you decide which IS to choose ?

Comment: Because `IS_2` contains `0006074909` **and** `00B1KHKN05`. Hence it should identify them both as a 'pair' and assign the correct label.

Answer (score 0):

```
# INPUT
id_dict = {"ID": ['0007650087', '00B64L8R37', '00B46FK959', '00B1KHKN05', '0008377250', '0001013456', '0001012268', '00B1KHLW60', '0006074909']}

is_dict = {'IS_1': ['0007650087', '00B64L8R37'],
 'IS_2': ['0006074909', '00B1KHKN05'],
 'IS_3': ['0006074909', '0001012267']}


# FUNCTION
def match_id(id_dict, is_dict):
    is_dict_list = [{"IS?": is_val, "ID": is_id} for is_val, is_id in is_dict.items()]
    is_df = pd.DataFrame(is_dict_list).explode('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
    id_df = pd.DataFrame(id_dict)
    res_df = pd.merge(id_df, is_df, on='ID', how='outer')
    return res_df


# IMPLEMENTATION
print(match_id(id_dict, is_dict))


# OUTPUT

            ID   IS?
0   0007650087  IS_1
1   00B64L8R37  IS_1
2   00B46FK959   NaN
3   00B1KHKN05  IS_2
4   0008377250   NaN
5   0001013456   NaN
6   0001012268   NaN
7   00B1KHLW60   NaN
8   0006074909  IS_2
9   0006074909  IS_3
10  0001012267  IS_3
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).